# Cardview over another view with elevation

Tags: xml, kotlin, overlap, cardview, elevation

How to make cardview over another view Like this image?

[image]

with cardview elevation and shadow ?

Comment: That is a recyclerview wherein  there are cardviews

Comment: The picture on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with the use of Guideline

Full code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="imageObject"
            type="com.payback.imagepicker.domain.model.image.Image" />

        <variable
            name="imageDetailsListener"
            type="com.payback.imagepicker.presentation.ui.image_details.ImageDetailsDialog" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <!-- image -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/img_place_holder"
            app:imageUrl="@{imageObject.imageLarge}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- image details container -->
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dp16w"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp4w"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- user name -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp16w"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/convergence"
                        android:text="@string/image_details_user_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sp21"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:text="@{imageObject.imageUserName}" />
                    <!-- image details -->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp16w"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/convergence"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/image_details_likes"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_like"
                            app:text="@{String.valueOf(imageObject.imageLikes)}" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp1w"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:background="@color/colorLine" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/convergence"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/image_details_comments"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_comment"
                            app:text="@{String.valueOf(imageObject.imageComments)}" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp1w"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:background="@color/colorLine" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp8w"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/convergence"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/image_details_downloads"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_download"
                            app:text="@{String.valueOf(imageObject.imageDownloads)}" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                    <!-- tags chips -->

                    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                        android:id="@+id/cg_image_details_chips"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp16w"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8w"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp16w"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp8w" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp90w"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp4h"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8w"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp8w"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrey" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGreyTransparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- guidelines -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />
        <!-- close -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_no_connection_close"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp55w"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp55h"
            android:onClick="@{()-> imageDetailsListener.onCloseClicked()}"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp16w"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```